# Open source portal suited for enterprise websites

Tags: open-source

I'm doing some evaluation on

Liferay vs [JBoss GateIn](http://www.jboss.org/gatein)

Looking for community info on which is better suited from points of view of:

- Performance
- Features OOTB
- In-life maintenance

I'm looking for **practical views (real-life sites)** or any gotchas you have come across in your own projects.

I asked this on [prog.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/open-source-portal-best-suited-for-enterprise-websites), but been asked to try here. Hope this is on-topic for this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used GateIn, but we've used Liferay For a couple of production sites and have been pretty happy with it.

Enterprise features that we've used extensively:

- multi-language
- multi-site (for serving web and mobile versions)
- structured content (for templating shops, restaurants, etc)

Performance has been troublesome for us in the past.  There is/was a bug in the version of Liferay 6 we were using that caused database connections to be exhausted which would bring down the admin site and required a reboot. But once patched db performance was good. I believe ythis bug is resolved in the latest version anyway.

Tuning of Apache and Tomcat also took some work.  OOTB Apache was spawning a lot of processes which chewed up memory. Again, once the tuning was complete we had no further issues and are now seeing 100% uptime.

Hope this helps.  If you need any specifics on the bugs, I can probably dig them out.

Comment: thanks - we did a PoC and are going ahead with Liferay, just fyi

Comment: Cool. It was only after I posted that I realised the question was from December. It popped up under active questions for some reason - maybe because of an edit.